# How to get value without json array from WCF service using android

Tags: wcf-data-services, android-json, android-json-rpc

```
{"username":"john",
"Location":"India"}
```

I have WCF service using JSON Object only but i don't know get value from without JSON Array.Please help any idea how to get value JSON using android

Answer (score 0):

Might be helpful for you

```
String fulURL = URL + "/GetLoginDetails/"
                + mtxt_UserID.getText().toString() + "/"
                + mtxt_Password.getText().toString() + "/" + deviceId;
        JSONObject jobject = doResponse(fulURL);

        if (jobject != null) {
            try {
                jarray = jobject.getJSONArray("GetCompanyInfo");
                status = jarray.getString(0);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```